# Can we use the Portable class library (Xamarin.Forms Portable) to share UI with ASP.Net application? How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I  have just started learning Xamarin.Forms.

I created a Xamarin.Forms portable class library and developed the UI which is working on all three mobile platforms (iOS, Android, Windows phone app).

But I want to know, is there any way that I can use that same UI code in an ASP.Net application? How would I do this?

I tried referencing a portable library but it didn't work.

Comment: i referred this tutorial for Xamarin.Forms ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xfMYdWAo0k )

Comment: What .net version your asp.net project targets and what subset does PCL library cover? What didn't worked exactly?

Comment: You can add PCL from Forms application without problems. However, you won't get views rendered in ASP.NET or Views in general for that matter. But you can reuse the ViewModel, Models and other Forms agnostic functionality, just not Views.

Comment: @MihaMarkic Thanks. 1) Yes Right, i have referenced PCL to ASP.Net but it is not rendering the UI so nothing is visible on browser when i run the application.    2) I understand that i can reuse Model,But not understand how to reuse ViewModel.

Comment: That depends on how your viewmodels are built. It is just code at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The XAML used by Xamarin Forms is only (currently) supported in iOS, Android and Windows Phone.